# How to remove android v7 -app compat support

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I am facing some problem in android suppport v7 app compat. is giving error that some jar missing. I want to make a simple hello world app with android support v4 or something, but how to remove android support v7?

Comment: remove dependency from project settings?

Comment: removing dependency is not working, its giving errors. when I remove those errors by removing action bar listener things, its still not showing anything when I run it.

Comment: 1) Remove it from dependencies.
2) Remove it from android library projects that are used in your project (if any).
3) Clean the project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit of a chore to remove it. It's easiest to just create a new project, unchecking "Create Activity" in the wizard and then add a new class to src.

But if you really, really want to remove the v7 stuff from an existing project, here's one way to remove it, the action bar, and the fragments stuff:

- Delete the android.libary.reference line from project.properties, ignoring the warning at the top.
- Change the type of MainActivity from ActionBarActivity to just Activity.
- Delete the v7 and v4.Fragment imports.
- Delete the **whole** "if (savedInstanceState)" statement from MainActivity.
- Delete the PlaceholderFragment class from MainActivity.
- Replace the contents of activty_main.xml file with the contents of fragment_main.mxl or your own layout.
- If you didn't use your own layout, remove the tools:context attribute/value from activity_main.xml.
- Edit each of the 3 styles.xml files (under values*) and change the parent of style AppBaseTheme to "android:Theme.Light" (or your choice).
- Edit menu/main.mxl and remove the app:showAsAction attribute/value.
- Organize imports and clean your project.

Just to be clear: this isn't something you really want to do for a real app, but more something that you might want to do if you're just creating a demo or proof of concept.

Edit:

Going forward, you can add an additional template that creates an Activity without appcompat_v7. You can get one by CommonsWare [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-rba). There's a nice write about it [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/15/really-blank-activity-why-appcompat-shoved-down-your-throat.html).

Comment: The above steps will remove it permanently from THAT project, but not any projects created later. The way to keep it out of newly created projects is to uncheck the "Create Activity" box in the new project wizard.

Comment: @scottt why don't you recommend this for a real app?  When I first started my project I wound up with the support lib being referenced.  I don't really need to support anything above 4.0,  and I carelessly ended up with a mix of Activities and ActionBarActivites. I would like to clean up this mess and was going to follow your outline, but noticed your "just to be clear comment" so I am balking.

Comment: @nPn - Eschewing use of the library goes against Google's guidelines to have your apps use fragments and an action bar. My "Just to be clear" comment was party to avoid down-votes by folks who take offense to not doing things the "Google way". And for most, following Google's guidelines will likely be easier in the long run. But if there's a good reason that an app shouldn't use those features, then there's nothing dreadful that will happen if you don't. To hedge your bets, save-off a version of your app before you make the changes in case you should find a compelling reason to switch back.

Comment: @scott If we don't care about Android versions below 4.0, it should be fine to remove appcompat, right?

Comment: @Inder - Yes, I believe so. Setting the Minimum Required SDK field to 14 or higher in the create new project wizard leaves out the v7 stuff. It does still include an android-support-v4.jar libary for some reason. AFAICT, simply deleting that library from the libs folder doesn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

For your information this happened because you upgraded your ADT to the most recent version (22 I think).